# Finding the representation matrix of the linear transformation $S: \mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow P_2: (a,b,c) \mapsto (a+b+c)+(3b-c)x$

Tags: linear-transformations

I know that the basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

Now, let $P_2(\mathbb{R}$ be the set of polynomials with degree less or equal to 2 with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $P_2(\mathbb{R}):=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x] | \text{degree}(p(x))\leq 2\}$.

I also know that the basis of $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\{(1,x)\}$ and with more simple examples I have no problem with this.

Now, let $$S: \mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow P_2(\mathbb{R}): (a,b,c) \mapsto (a+b+c)+(3b-c)x$$ How do I find the matrix of "S"?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What do you denote $P_2$?

Comment: The set of linear polynomials with degree less than 2, so of the form $p(x)=a+bx$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The matrix of a linear map has as column vectors the coordinates, in the basis of $P_2$, of the images of the vectors of the basis used for $\mathbf R^3$.

(Incidentally, there is no such thing as THE basis of a vector space: $\mathbf R^3$ has an infinite number of bases. The basis you mention is usually considered as the *canonical basis* of $\mathbf R^3$).

Comment: Thanks, yes i should have said that in this case they were in respect to the standard bases.  It's the images of the vectors in the basis for $R^3$ that's causing me the problem!

Comment: Can't you calculate $S(1,0,0)$, $S(0,1,0)$ and $S(0,0,1)$?

Comment: Well, what i'm getting is $(3b-c,0,0), (0,3b-c,0),(0,0,3b-c)$ but i'm pretty sure this is completely wrong and don't know how to proceed then to find the coordinates in the basis of $P_2$

Comment: But there can be no $a,b$ or $c$ in the answer: they should represent the coordinates of vectors in the basis!

Comment: Which is why I was sure it was wrong! So, in answer to can i not calculate the images, no i can't!! Would I replace the a,b,c with x,y,z?

Comment: No, with $1,0,0$, $\;0,1,0$ and $0,0,1$ successively.

Comment: so, (1,0,0),(0,1+3x,0).(0,0,01)? still wrong i think

Comment: The *coordinates* in $P_2$  don't use $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand that a matrix represents a given matrix only in a given choice of basis for both domain and range spaces?  What bases do you want to use?  A natural choice would be {(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)} for the domain space and {1, x} for the range space. Apply the transformation to each of the domain space basis vectors in turn and write the result in terms of the range space basis.  Each gives a column of the matrix representation.

This transformation maps (1, 0, 0) into 1+ 0x so first column of the matrix is (1, 0).  The transformation maps (0, 1, 0) into 1+ 3x so the second column of the matrix is (1, 3). The transformation maps (0, 0, 1) into 1- x so the third column of the matrix is (1, -1).  The matrix representation of the linear transformation **using these choices of basis** is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Huge help, thank you..I was sort of getting there with the previous help but not quite!  And yes, i do understand all that, thanks!  struggling mature student here!